# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'old_db' when in '.env' a new db is defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

After the database has moved to a different server and a different schema name, I updated the `.env` file and when entering `php artisan config:cache` it writes the error message

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'OLD_DB'" - (OLD_DB refers to
>   the database name before the change).

I don't know why it still looks for the old name as if I didn't update the `.env` file. I also tried to write `php artisan cache:clear` and even just `php artisan` alone and received this error. Also composer update did not help - in the end it tries to run `@php artisan package:discover`.

Comment: try `php artisan clear:cache`

Comment: And `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: As mentioned every "php artisan ___" command failed, including "php artisan" alone.

Comment: did you try composer dump-autoload ? @GuyArnon

Comment: are you using single environment for your application?. If not did you move file between.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I managed to solve the problem by clearing the cache:

```
rm -f bootstrap/cache/*
```

This allowed me to (finally) run:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and the new configuration was on the air.